# Ansible variable undefined

Tags: configuration, vagrant, jinja2, ansible

Why can't I access the variable I defined as group var in the *inventory file* from the `playbook.yml`?

Here is the content of `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- name: test ansible local provisioning
  hosts: all
  vars:
    playbook_var: "playbook_var"
  tasks:
    - name: Test ansible is working
      debug: msg="Ansible seems to be working, this variable is from plabook {{ playbook_var }} and this variable is from hosts file {{ hosts_file_var }}"
```

And here is `hosts`:

```
[all:vars]
hosts_file_var="hosts_file_var"
```

Ansible throws the following error:

```
TASK [Test ansible is working] *************************************************  
fatal: [ansible_host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'hosts_file_var' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/provisioning/ansible_host/playbook.yml': line 7, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
  tasks:
    - name: Test ansible is working
      ^ here
"}
```

Is there some aspect I don't understand about how Ansible processes variables?

Here is also the `ansible.cfg`. I'm willing to use Ansible for Vagrant provisioning:

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
remote_user = vagrant
```

Comment: Your playbook and the inventory file are ok. Running them results in: `"msg": "Ansible seems to be working, this variable is from plabook playbook_var and this variable is from hosts file hosts_file_var"`. Your main error message is `'hosts_file_var' is undefined`, so it seems like you are not using the inventory file you posted.

Comment: And your error message is exactly the one that I get when omitting `-i` argument in `ansible-playbook` call.

Comment: On top of that, if the `hosts` you posted in the question is complete, Ansible should throw an error, so if you don't get an error, then your Ansible uses a different one.

Answer (score 3):

Problem was wrong inventory file was used, thus variables where undefined. Here is the long explanation why that happened in the first place.

The issue is how vagrant executes `ansible-playbook`command. Default working directory to execute the command in guest is not the path given for `ansible.playbook` configuration, but `/vagrant` (which is synced relatively to Vagrantfile by default). This can be confirmed by examining output given by following configuration:

`ansible.verbose = true`

The solution was to provide following configuration (note that `ansible.playbook` is relative to this directory in guest, and doesn't have to do anything in host location.

`ansible.provisioning_path = "/vagrant/provisioning/ansible_host"`

Vagrant also generates it's own inventory file and executes following command, if no additional configuration is given.

```
Running ansible-playbook...
cd /vagrant/provisioning/ansible_host && PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ansible-playbook --limit="ansible-host" --inventory-file=/tmp/vagrant-ansible/inventory -v playbook.yml
Using /vagrant/provisioning/ansible_host/ansible.cfg as config file
```

Here's all the necessary configuration to get things work

```
ansible_host.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  ansible.provisioning_path = "/vagrant/provisioning/ansible_host"
  ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"
  ansible.limit = "all"
  ansible.verbose = true
end
```

Note that is's also necessary to declare `ansible_connection=local` host/group var for localhost entry

Comment: The connection between your question and your answer is limited to your account name in the footer.

Comment: Pardon me, I formatted the answer to be more clear now.